# Faster file lookup

Tags: c#, performance, file-system

I'm polling an ashx handler to check if a specific file is present and return true or false depending on it.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    int myId;
    if (context.IsRequestClean())
    {
        if (int.TryParse(context.Request["id"], out myId))
        {
            var directory = Directory.GetDirectories(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files"), "*" + myId, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            if (directory.Length > 0)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(directory[0][directory[0].Length - 1].ToString()) == myId)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    context.Response.Write("true");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I speed the above up?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a shorter time between file is created until the client is notified, I recomment you implement long-running queries, for example using SignalR.

Then setup a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that notifies the query as soon as the file is present.

Comment: Short example of how you would do it with signalr?

Comment: I think this tutorial is pretty good:http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5

Comment: Okay. Saw that. It would be a hectic task to do that now. BTW, I'll take your `FileSystemWatcher` advice. +1 for that